# Fragment lifecycle - Code execuded before the layout is visible onscreen

Tags: android, android-fragments

Where should I put code to be executed before a fragment is visible? Like in `MainFragement.kt`, I need to check if the user is logged in and if not he's directed to the `LoginFragmet.kt` and if Logged in he's directed to `HomeFragment.kt`

Comment: I'm considering `onAttach()` but not confident that should be the case.

Comment: In your activity (I think you are considering your MainActivity as MainFragment) check if your user is logged in or not and if not then show the login fragment else show the Login fragment.

Answer (score 0):

When we are working with fragment there will be mostly an activity where the fragment needs to be attached so from there we can check that if current user is logged in or not and based on that we will show the fragment

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var homeFragment: Fragment = HomeFragment();
    private var loginFragment: Fragment = LoginFragment();
    private lateinit var currentFragment: Fragment;
    
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        
        if(isCurrentUserLoggedIn())
            currentFragment = homeFragment
        else
            currentFragment = loginFragment
        
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.my_fragment_container, currentFragment)
        
        
    }

    private fun isCurrentUserLoggedIn(): Boolean {
        var userLoginStatus: Boolean = false;
        
        /* Check whether your user is logged in or not */
        
        return userLoginStatus;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** above code is just for the sample it's needs to be created as required and with proper requirements